# mongodb math operations on two fields in collection

Tags: mongodb

Hello i have exercise to filter all countries where gdp is greater than 0.05 on one person in country. I need to take the latest year of population. Also code of the country should have at least 3 characters. My collection looks like this:

```
mondial.countries
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581cb5a519ec2deb4ba71c03"),
    "name" : "Germany",
    "code" : "GER",
    "capital" : "RN-Niamey-Niamey",
    "area" : 1267000,
    "gdp" : 7304,
    "inflation" : 1.9,
    "unemployment" : null,
    "independence" : ISODate("1960-08-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "government" : "republic",
    "population" : [
        {
            "year" : 1950,
            "value" : 2559703
        },
        {
            "year" : 1960,
            "value" : 3337141
        },
        {
            "year" : 1970,
            "value" : 4412638
        },
        {
            "year" : 1977,
            "value" : 5102990
        },
        {
            "year" : 1988,
            "value" : 7251626
        },
        {
            "year" : 1997,
            "value" : 9113001
        },
        {
            "year" : 2001,
            "value" : 11060291
        },
        {
            "year" : 2012,
            "value" : 17138707
        }
    ]
}
```

For this example I have to take the population from year 2012 a divide it by gdp a then display it if its greater than 50000. I have been trying with function in js but idk how to show fields that are greater thatn 5000 of my operation. What is the easies way to do this?

```
var countries = db.mondial.countries.find({
"code": {$gte: 3},
});

while(countries.hasNext()) {
    gdp = countries.next()
    gdpresult = countries.population / gdp.gdp
    
    print(gdpresult)
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly. more see if it helps

```
db.mondial.aggregate([
{
    $match:{
         $expr: {
             $gte:['$code',3 ]
         }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        gdpresult: {
            $map: {
                input: '$population',
                as: 'p',
                in: {
                    value: {
                        $divide: ["$$p.value", '$gdp']
                    },
                    year: '$$p.year'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```